# How can we structure array of dictionary in firebase realtime database?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create below json structure like in firebase realtime databse

```
{
    "doner": [
        {
            "firstName": "Sandesh",
            "lastName": "Sardar",
            "location": [50.11, 8.68],
            "mobile": "100",
            "age": 21
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Akash",
            "lastName": "saw",
            "location": [50.85, 4.35],                
            "mobile": "1200",                
            "age": 22                
        },            
        {                
            "firstName": "Sahil",                
            "lastName": "abc",                
            "location": [48.85, 2.35],                
            "mobile": "325846",                
            "age": 23                
        },            
        {                
            "firstName": "ram",                
            "lastName": "abc",                
            "location": [46.2039, 6.1400],                
            "mobile": "3257673",                
            "age": 34                
        }]        
}
```

But when I imported file in firebase realtime database, it turns into below structure where [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hohnJ.png)

I believe this is not array of dictionary, but it is a dictionary of multiple dictionaries.

Is there any way to structure array of dictionaries in firebase?

Comment: What is your problem with the generated structure? Every entry has a key, you can think about the firebase real-time database as a json

Comment: @barotia as per my understanding I am not able to iterate doner directly using index of array but because of firebase structure, I will have to iterate using key.

Comment: Umm, why is that a problem?

Comment: @barotia because if I will have to add or delete something in database I will have to find key for that. i guess if I have array i can simply delete, append using index

Comment: With firebase you won't delete using index anyway, for deleting you'll have to add a path for a specific child, for that an Id is required.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't natively store arrays in the format you want. It instead stores arrays as key-value pairs, with the key being the (string representation) of the index of each item in the array.

When you read the data from Firebase (either through an SDK, or through the REST API), it converts this map back into an array.

So what you're seeing is the expected behavior, and there's no way to change it.

If you'd like to learn more about how Firebase deals with arrays, and why, I recommend checking out Kato's blog post here: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).